# Find user from email address

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I would like to use `find` to return a user based on an email address.

Something in the lines of:

```
Meteor.users.find({emails : [address : 'aa@gmail.com']} ).fetch()
```

It didn't work, how can I retrieve a user this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query :

```
function findByEmail(email){
  var user = Meteor.users.find({
    "emails.address": email
  }).fetch();
  return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query user by email like this:

```
Users.find({ email: "useremail@example.com" }).fetch();
```

Comment: This works but I had to add one more field like Users.find({ email: "useremail@example.com" , verified: false}).fetch(); The accepted answer is elegant I think